# why does my button need to be clicked twice to trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to detect a duplicate everytime i type something new in `input`, i use a simple `for loops`, the problem is i need to click the button twice if the the new input is not a duplicate, but if the new input is a duplicate it works just fine, here is my code

```
teken(event){
    this.setState({nama: event.target.value});
    const angka = todos.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
      {if(todos[i].nama === this.state.value){
        this.setState({beda: false})
        alert("tidak boleh sama")
        break
      }else if(this.state.beda != false){
        this.setState({beda: true})
      }
    }
    }
    if(this.state.beda){
      alert("gas")
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

i already tried other solutions but it still doesnt work, any help will be appreciated, thanks before

Answer (score 1):

this.setState() is an asynchronous function. You cannot guarantee that it will update the state value before it reaches your alert code.

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is, you comparing the `todos[i].nama` with `this.state.value` (which is not updated yet with the current `e.target.value`, because `this.setState` works asynchronously).
I'd suggest to do it this way:

```
teken(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const newValue = event.target.value

  this.setState({ nama: newValue});
  const angka = todos.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
    if(todos[i].nama === newValue){
      this.setState({ beda: false })
      alert("tidak boleh sama")
      alert("gas")
      break
    }else if(this.state.beda != false){
      this.setState({beda: true})
    }
  }
}
```

for more explanation:

```
// let's say we have this.state.counter = 0
test() {
   this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
   console.log(this.state.counter) // --> will console 0, because it's async
}
```

if you want to access the `this.state.counter` with the updated data, you can do:

```
this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.counter)
})
```